# form of bootstrap is narrow and cols parameter does not work

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn bootstrap on my site but the form is just too narrow that I cannot change the width by changing the text field's cols.

see the page:

http://saslab.org/mycontact.php

and this page:

http://saslab.org/testme.html

could some one educate me on this?

thank you!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">                                     
        <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    </div> 
    <div class="span4">    
        <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
    </div>
</div>
```

wrap the p tag and input with span

Answer (score 0):

You have a line in your source: `<div class="container marketing">`. Upon further inspection, your 'marketing' class has the attribute `text-align:center`. This means all of your form will be centered because the div that contains it has that class. This is why your form is narrow.

Specifically, you have a file called mycontact.php and here's what you have for the CSS that applies:

```
.marketing .span12 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sure, am I supposed to be looking for anything in particular?

Answer (score 0):

well, i guess it is Bootstrap's default css that causes the narrowing.  in the following links, you can see the contrast

one without bootstrap:

http://saslab.org/testme.html

one with bootstrap:

http://saslab.org/testme_bootstrap.html